# Aggregate fields in DTO

Tags: rest, design-patterns, ef-code-first, automapper, dto

I have some architectural/pattern question. Suppose that i have a domain model with two classes. I use Code First and Repository Pattern. (To make it more simple in the example I use only fields, not properties)

```
public class Person {
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public string Surname;
    public virtual ICollection<Pet> Pets;
}
public class Pet {
    public string Name;
    public int BirthYear;
    public int OwnerId;
    public Person Owner;
}
```

I also have PersonDto, and PetDto classes, with the only difference, that Pets field in PersonDto is a simple List. I use Automapper to transform model classes to dto. Dto are next sent to the client through REST Api. Now, what if on some view I need to show for every Person its Name, Surname and PetCount (lets assume that there are so many pets that it would make it very inefficient to pull them from database and simply count them on the view).

Now - what would be the correct approach to introduce PetCount. Should I put this field in the PersonDto as well as in the Person class, and prevent it from creating column in the database (it doesn't seem right for me). Or maybe I should only create PetCount field in PersonDto - but then when to count this value, in the repository method or maybe while mapping (the latter also doesn't seem right for me). Another question is if I should create an extra field in PetDto, or maybe I should inherit PersonDto with PersontWithPetCountDto, or maybe I should create PersontWithPetCountDto class without inheritance, but with PetCount field and all the fields from PersonDto

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `PetCount` attribute of `Person`, then you can reach it from `Pet` via the `Owner` attribute. The question therefore is reduced to whether we want a `PetCount` attribute for `Person`. The answer will be the result of a choice. The choice can be wisely made if you ask yourself the right questions:

- how often will this value be used?
- how long will updating this number take?
- how often is this number changing?

In general, if you reach to the conclusion that you need a `PetCount`, then you will need to make sure that:

1. On inserting a `Pet` you update its `Owner`'s `PetCount` as well
2. On updating a `Pet` you will make sure its old `Owner`'s and new `Owner`'s `PetCount` is updated if the `Owner` changed
3. On removing a `Pet` its `Owner`'s PetCount is updated
4. You use transactions to make sure that upon any kind of failure in the operations above the state will be rolled back to the previous state

If you reach to the conclusion that you do not need a `PetCount` attribute, you will need to calculate it each time when you need it.

You can use a hybrid solution as well, involving a caching system. The optimal choice is up to you.